# How to insert a reply inline in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

When replying to an email in Gmail, how do I write my reply **within** the text of the sender's email?

I can do this with other email programs, but how do I do it in Gmail?

Answer (score 15):

Click the ellipsis at the bottom of the response textarea:
[image: Gmail response window ellipsis]

This will show the text you are replying to, and allow you to reply within that text.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramal What do you mean by "allow you to reply within that text", I'm still stuck

Comment: @hello_there_andy What happens when you click the ellipsis? In my case, it shows the entire message that I'm replying to. When I click within that message, a blinking cursor appears, and when I type text, the text is inserted within that message.

Comment: *facepalm* I was clicking on the ellipsis on the other user's email, and not in my response area

Answer (score 11):

You can also highlight (drag the mouse cursor) over a block of text in the original email message and then click "Reply".

If you do that, you will get a quoted reply

`> Original text line 1
> Original text line 2

My reply`

Comment: not any more, they removed that very useful feature. :(